# Find the longest string in matrix a, recursively - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, matrix, vector

I want to find the longest string (most repeated char) in a given matrix using recursion. The input given by the user is the matrix, and the start position of the recursion. Another thing is that each element of the matrix can be "checked" by the recursive function only once.

So here is an example:

If my matrix looks like this:

```
abcdeaab
adfdgagh
madafaff
abaacafr
```

The result should be `start=(5,0), stop=(5,4), c='a'`. The result is this, because the char 'a', is the longest string in the matrix, that starts at position (5,0) and ends at (5,4). As you can see, the matrix has to be checked on horizontally and also vertically.

I didn't really used much recursion in past, that's why I got stuck in here.

I've read the article here: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Recursion/recursionsimple.html. I understand that in order to achieve what I want to achieve, my program has to obey the three laws of recursion:

- A recursive algorithm must have a base case.
- A recursive algorithm must change its state and move toward the base case.
- A recursive algorithm must call itself, recursively.

I started to write the code, and got up to here:

```
#!/bin/python2.7

#Longest string in matrix

#Given a matrix filled with letters. Find the longest string, containing only the same letter, which can be obtained by starting
#with any position and then moving horizontally and vertically (each cell can be visited no more than 1 time).


# Settings here
# -------------
string_matrix = """
abcdeaab
adfdgagh
madafaff
abaacafr
"""
pos = (0,0)
# -------------

rows = 0
columns = 0
matrix = []
matrix2 = []


def stop():
    for l in matrix2:
        for c in l:
            if c == '1':
                return True
    return False

def search(pos):
    # my base case
    if stop():
        return

    global matrix2
    # matrix2 keeps track of the visited elements of matrix
    matrix2[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 1



def main():
    # create the matrix from string
    string_matrix_l = string_matrix.strip()
    splited = string_matrix_l.split('\n')

    global rows
    global columns
    global matrix
    global matrix2

    rows = len(splited)
    columns = len(splited[1])

    # initialize matrix with 0
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for x in range(rows)]
    matrix2 = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for x in range(rows)]

    # print some info
    print 'Given matrix: ' + str(matrix) + '\n'
    print 'Start position: ' + str(pos)

    # set matrix from string
    i = 0
    for s in splited:
        s = s.strip()
        if s == '':
            continue

        j = 0

        for c in s:
            try:
                matrix[i][j] = c
                #print 'ok: ' + str(i) + ' ' + str(j) + ' ' +  c
            except:
                print 'fail: index out of range matrix[' + str(i) + '][' + str(j)+'] ' + c
            j = j + 1

        i = i + 1

        #print s
        #print matrix


    # get the result
    search(pos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What my program does (for now), is converting a string into a matrix, and creating another matrix, called matrix2, which will keep track of the elements visited from matrix by the search (recursive) function.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Is is not clear what "longest string" is in your question.

Comment: Gave an example, longest string in a matrix: a string that has the same character like 'aaaaa' or 'cccccccc'. But it has to work on horizontally and also veritcally

Comment: Do you mean the most repeated char? How is a the longest char in your example?

Comment: yes, that would be more clear :D edited the question as well.

Comment: You are trying to solve the Longest Path problem, which is generally is NP-Complete. It is easy to solve it efficiently in a DAG, but your problem is not it. How big is your matrix going to be?

Comment: not very big, this is just something that I want to do to understand recusivity better, could be 20x20 maximum.

Comment: 20x20 is a lot for an NP-Hard problem. For some instances it will be fine, but it might take decades for other, "hard" instances.

Comment: let's just put it 10x5, will work as well.

Comment: In your example what is `(4,5)`? your numbers are 0-based but your structure does not have 5 rows.

Comment: They seem to be `(y, x)`.

Comment: Ye, sorry for the confusion, they are (y,x), will change it to (x,y)

Comment: Take a look at this. It's a tough tough problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this problem is hard to solve, and there is no known efficient solution to it, it is called the [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)

To find longest path from one cell, you can use a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to solve it, which is recursive algorithm by nature.

Python like pseudo-code:

```
DFS((x,y),visited):
   maxPathLength = -1
   for each neighbor (x1,y1) of (x,y):
        #skip visited nodes, or nodes that are not the same character:
        if (x1,y1) in visited of arr[x][y] != arr[x1][y1]:
           continue
        #node is not visited and same character.
        #mark it as visited:
        visited.add((x1,y1))
        #recurse and store what the longest path found by recursion:
        currLength = DFS((x1,y1),visited)
        #set the max out of all paths:
        maxPathLength = max(maxPathLength, currLength)
   #clean up
   visited.remove((x,y))
   #return an answer:
   return maxPathLength  + 1
```

It follows your 3 points for recursive algorithms because:

- The stop clause in the code: If there are no "unvisited" nodes, the
  algorithm will return 0 without invoking the recursive call.
- The algorithm changes the state of the visited nodes, and moves on to the next neighbor, until there is no possible path left, which will be the stop clause.
- The algorithm calls itself recursively for each possible "neighbor" of the current cell.

This algorithm will yield you the longest path from some source cell. You can repeat it for all cells to find the "global" longest path.

This algorithm only provides the *length* of the longest path, but it is pretty easy to modify it to also remember the path itself, by returning a tuple `(length,list)` - where list is the cells visited in this path.